# getting column not found when trying to reference a type in relationship table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how would i get the type name of my referenced table in my get

Here is my database example:

```
mainTable
id | typeid
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
```

And here is my second table

```
typesTable
id | type
1  | test
2  | test2
3  | test3
```

My relationship in my main table model is defined as :

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\typesTable', 'typeID');
}
```

And here is how im pulling the data:

```
try {
            $data = Main::with('type')
            ->groupBy('typeID')
            ->get(array(
                DB::raw('type as date') <---getting type column does not exist-->,
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
            ));

            return Respond::Ok('Success', $data);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return Respond::Bad('Failed', $th);
        }
```

my problem is i cannot get the type name in my get array and am getting an error..

if i remove that line i get the following data back:

```
message: "Success"
data: 
0: {views: 2, type: null}
1: {views: 1, type: null}
2: {views: 1, type: null}
meta: null
```

Please help

Comment: Try with `type.id` in get().

Comment: getting type.id column does not exist

Comment: Remove `DB::raw()` function and try

Comment: i have removed db raw
->get(array(
                'type.id',
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
            ));
and still getting the same error

Comment: try with `typeid` or `typeID`.

Comment: so type id i can get but i need the type name